# Raising non-Exception based exceptions in Python gives different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I just noticed that the following code written in Python 2.x doesn't go to the `except`-block

```
class MyException:
    pass

try:
    raise MyException()
except Exception:
    print('Exception')
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 5, in
<module>
    raise MyException()
__main__.MyException: <__main__.MyException instance at 0x021E9DC8>
```

while the following code does:

```
try:
    raise 'str'
except Exception:
    print('Exception')
```

**Output**

```
Exception
```

The same goes for `raise 0` expression, for example.

Why? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I can't answer why exactly Python 2 ended up that way, but it's been changed in Python 3, where you can no longer raise objects that don't inherit from `BaseException`. Even if you do figure out the exact logic, I wouldn't recommend using it in any code you need to maintain going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for python 2.7:
`raise 'str'` and `raise 0` will both raise `TypeError`. This will be handled by the `except Exception` branch in your code.

Since your own class `MyException` doesn't inherit from `Exception`, the `except` branch is never executed. You could still do:

```
try:
     raise MyException()
except MyException:
     print('Exception')
```

In your example the output `__main__.MyException: <__main__.MyException instance at 0x021E9DC8>` was printed by `sys.excepthook` (the top-level exception handler), because you never caught the exception.

Comment: And why it is `TypeError` for such types like integers and strings but not for the user-defined classes that doesn't inherit from `Exception` class?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Try to raise 0 in the interactive shell, you should get TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not int